# Left alignment of text and icon in bootstrap button with custom image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble horizontal aligning in button working with bootstrap framework. I've tried so many things and I have read a lot but my solution is not working. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

The idea is to align to left the text of the button, The attached image is the output of the following html:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="bCheckIn" value="action01">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/CheckIn.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Check in</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="bactivities" value="action02">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/Activities.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Activities</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="bBottle" value="action03">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/Bottle.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Bottle</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="bComputer" value="action04">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/ComputerTime.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Computer</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="bDiaper" value="action05">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/Diaper.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Diaper</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

[image: How to align to left?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text-align: left` css property can affect `inline` and `inline-block` elements and you can use it for left alignment.

**EDIT:**

If you are using `.btn-group` in many places in your site and you wants all of them as left aligned then apply generic styles to affect all occurrences of `.btn-group` like shown below:

```
.btn-group .btn-default {
    text-align: left;
}
```

However if you have many `.btn-group` at many places but you wants `left-align` only one of them then better add additional custom class on `.btn-group` and style with this as shown below.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified custom-btn-group">
     // content goes here...
</div>
```

And styles as follows:

```
.custom-btn-group .btn-default {
    // styles goes here...
}
```

***Note:*** See Demo in Full Page mode.

```css
.btn-group .btn-default {
  text-align: left;
}

.btn-group .btn-default span,
.btn-group .btn-default img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="bCheckIn" value="action01">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/CheckIn.png" width="35" height="35"/>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Check in</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="bactivities" value="action02" >
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/Activities.png" width="35" height="35"/>
       <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Activities</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="bBottle" value="action03">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/Bottle.png" width="35" height="35"/>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Bottle</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="bComputer" value="action04">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/ComputerTime.png" width="35" height="35"/>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Computer</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="bDiaper" value="action05">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/Diaper.png" width="35" height="35"/>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Diaper</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! you are a Genius!

Comment: if you give left align to .btn-group .btn-default class then it will affect all site, you need to add your custom class.

Comment: @VishalPanara As we are not sure about this. May be `.btn-group` is not using any other place in site. I suppose OP knows about this and he can use custom class if needed.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman As we are not sure about this. May be .btn-group may using any other place in site I suppose OP may not knows about this and you need to mention it. :P

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code in your editor, This is happening because the class `.btn` use `text-align:center` by default and i overwrite it to `text-align:left` with new custom class `.mytest`

```css
.mytext{
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default mytext" id="bCheckIn" value="action01">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/CheckIn.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Check in</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default mytext" id="bactivities" value="action02">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/Activities.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Activities</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default mytext" id="bBottle" value="action03">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/Bottle.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Bottle</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default mytext" id="bComputer" value="action04">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/ComputerTime.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Computer</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default mytext" id="bDiaper" value="action05">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/Diaper.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Diafgfgfgper</span>
    </a>

</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default mytext" id="bCheckIn" value="action01">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/CheckIn.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Check in</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default mytext" id="bactivities" value="action02">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/Activities.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Activfgfgities</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default mytext" id="bBottle" value="action03">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/Bottle.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Bofggttle</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default mytext" id="bComputer" value="action04">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/ComputerTime.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Cofgggmputer</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default mytext" id="bDiaper" value="action05">
        <img src="http://localhost/daycare/assets/img/activities/Diaper.png" width="35" height="35" align="left" />
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Digfgaper</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

*simply should not change the base classes of bootstrap as it will effect on whole site so better use with custom class*